# Как ограничить права доступа не авторизированным пользователям в codeiginiter-3.1.5

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->helper(array('url', 'form'));
      $this->load->model("usermodel");
      $this->load->library('session');
    }

  private function view($page, $data=false) {
      if($page == "auth/login" ){
            $this->load->view("auth/header_auth.php");
        }else{
            $this->load->view("header.php");
      }

      $this->load->view($page, $data);
      $this->load->view("footer.php");
  }

  public function index() {
      if ($this->session->userdata("user")) {
          redirect("dashboard", "refresh");
          return;
      }else{
      redirect("auth/login", "refresh");
      }
      }


  public function register() {
      $this->view("auth/register");
  }

  public function fail() {
      $this->view("auth/login");

  }

  public function dashboard() {
      $this->view("auth/dashboard");
  }

  public function login() {
      $login = $this->input->post("login");
      $password = $this->input->post("password");
      if ($this->usermodel->login($login, $password)) {
          $this->session->set_userdata("user", $login);
          redirect("dashboard", "refresh");
      } else {
          redirect("fail", "refresh");
      }
  }

  public function new_register() {
      $name = $this->input->post("userName");
      $login = $this->input->post("login");
      $type = $this->input->post("userType");
      $email = $this->input->post("e-mail");
      $password = $this->input->post("password");
      $passwordConf = $this->input->post("passwordConf");

      $this->usermodel->register($name, $login, $type, $email, $password, $passwordConf);
      redirect("register", "refresh");
  }

   public function logout() {
      $this->session->unset_userdata('user');
      session_destroy();
      redirect('index', 'refresh');
    }

}
```

Это контроллер user.php.
Функция авторизации login();
Хелп :(

Comment: А что делает функция авторизации? просто сравнивает с бд и возвращает TRUE?

Comment: +++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: ну тогда хьюстон у нас проблемы. Если вам нужен безопасный сайт, то нужно делать систему авторизации абсолютно иначе. Если безопасность не интересует, то просто при авторизации (где вы в сессию записываете логин) записывайте и группу пользователя, и при каждом обращении на запрещенные страницы смотреть группу пользователя (но это сильный костыль, надо изначально делать по уму).